# Using psql meta-commands in Django connection cursor?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having trouble passing a command with a backslash in it to `django.connection.cursor` (with a Postgres backend):

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
copy_str = "\\copy my_table FROM 'my_table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV";
cursor.execute(copy_str)
```

But this gives me:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"
```

Using a single slash gives me the same error.

Can I use backslashes with `django.connection.cursor`, or should I fall back to `psycopg2`?

The only reason I'm not using `psycopg2` in the first place is that I am using the Django ORM elsewhere in the same script, so it would be convenient to use it here too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) with the `r` prefix:

```
copy_str = r"\\copy my_table FROM 'my_table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

But are you sure that this is valid SQL syntax?

Comment: Doesn't help, I'm afraid. Yes, it's valid in psql (it's a meta-command).

Comment: Meta-commands are processed by `psql` not by PostgreSQL.  So you can't use them from any other client. Direct use of `psycopg2` will not help you.